# grails Mongodb plugin not visible in plugins

Tags: mongodb, grails, plugins

I'm trying to install mongodb plugin with grails 2.3.4 and using Spring Tool Suite 3.4(Sts).when I try to install mongodb without hibernate plugin.It doesn't show me plugin in plugins but when I check for that plugin in the project directory it creates a folder with the plugin's name i.e. mongodb-1.3.3 and puts few  configuration file but doesnt show actually plugin code.

**Here is my buildConfig.groovy :**

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5     or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable    ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or  'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not   advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from  public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or  'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    //runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
    //runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    compile ":mongodb:1.3.3"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
}
}
```

Please suggest me what actually I'm missing.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Grails plugin mongodb-1.3.3 is only supports Grails 2.1.4 and Grails 2.2.1 .

Comment: Thanks for the solution,Can you please tell me which version of this plugin is compatible with Grails 2.3.4

Comment: 1.3.3 is the latest one, and should be fine in 2.3.4.  There appears to have been an issue with 1.2.0, but even that supports 2.2.1 "and above". [Documentation here](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb).